# Tips on using offline images with react native

Tags: react-native

I'm working with images fetched via API endpoint and displaying them on the application's home screen. The images should be displayed even if the user is offline. The problem is that sometimes, the images were not showed at all or some of them were missing, this only happens on release builds, when I'm testing it on emulator, there is almost every time 0 problem, but when it happens on emulator, it usually said that the image file:///XXX were not found.

I'v tried a lot of packages including:
[react-native-image-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-offline),
[react-native-img-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-img-cache),
[react-native-cached-image](https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image).
I'v also tried [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) which was only one that displayed images correctly (displayed all of them) but it does not support offline. Finally I tried to create my own "Cached image" component based on react-native-fs library which was working great on emulator, but on a real device, the app was not able to display a single image. (code below)

I'v also tried to read as many articles as I can, but I could not find any that was working for my app. Most of them were just relying on some of the package mentioned above.

```
class CachedImage extends React.Component {

state = { source: null }

loadFile = ( path )=> {
  this.setState({ source:{uri: path}})
 }

downloadFile = (uri,path) => {
  RNFS.downloadFile({fromUrl:uri, toFile: path}).promise
  .then(res =>{
    this.loadFile(path)
  })
 }

componentDidMount(){
  const { uri, objId } = this.props;
  const extension = (Platform.OS === 'android') ? 'file://' : ''
  const path =`${extension}${RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath}/${objId}.png`
  RNFS.exists(path).then( exists => {
    if(exists){
      this.loadFile(path)
    } else {
      this.downloadFile(uri,path)
    }
  })
 }

 render(){
   return(
     <Image style = {this.props.style} source = {this.state.source} />
   )
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate any recommendations like what are you using to store images? Did you faced the same problem and what was the reason of it? Thank you.

Comment: have you try with dummy data 1st on your component ?

Comment: Yes I did and it worked just fine..